# Array, compare two elements of the array, simple card game, c++

Tags: c++, arrays, compare, element

In short, im making a simple game.

Draw a card from the deck and decide a winner.

If the player draws a higher card, a more powerful card he wins. If the computer draws a higher card the computer wins.

The power of the cards goes from ace (weakest), then 1 stronger, 2 stronger, 3 stronger, etc king strongest.  If the player draws an ace and the computer draws an king, the player loses.

The cards are stacked in the array from weakest, ace, to strongest king. Total 52 cards as there is in a card game.

The array looks like this. From ace to king.

```
array<string, 52> cards = { "ace \3", "ace \4", "ace \5", "ace \6","2 \3","2 \4","2 \5","2 \6","3 \3","3 \4","3 \5","3 \6","4 \3","4 \4","4 \5","4 \6","5 \3","5 \4","5 \5","5 \6","6 \3","6 \4","6 \5","6 \6","7 \3","7 \4","7 \5","7 \6","8 \3","8 \4","8 \5","8 \6","9 \3","9 \4","9 \5","9 \6","10 \3","10 \4","10 \5","10 \6","Jacks \3","Jacks \4","Jacks \5","Jacks \6","Queen \3","Queen \4","Queen \5","Queen \6","King \3","King \4","King \5","King \6" };



The function.
string draw_card() {
    int random_index = rand() % 52;
    string card = cards[random_index];
    return card;
}

int main()
{
    srand ( (unsigned int)time(NULL) );

string you_drew = draw_card();                          // calling the function and storing the card in the variable you_drew
cout << "You drew: " << you_drew << endl;

string comp_drew = draw_card();
cout << "The computer drew: " << comp_drew << endl;     // calling the function and storing the card in the variable computer_drew
```

This so far is working Correctly.

Now here is my problem..

I want to decide a winner.
The one with the most powerful card should win and I can not figure this out...

Currently the deciding a winner looks like this.

```
    int your_score{ 0 };
    int the_computers_score{ 0 };


    if (you_drew > comp_drew) {
        cout << "You Won!" << endl;
        your_score++;
    }
    else if (comp_drew > you_drew) {
        cout << "You Lost.." << endl;
        the_computers_score++;
    }


    return 0;
}
```

It almost always declares the wrong winner, the program isnt working..
My way of comparing, to decide a winner is not working.
How do I decide a winner?

I think I have to compare the elements within the array with each other... and the element further away should be the most powerful.
How do I do this?

The values, the cards from the elements of the array is stored correctly in the variables **you_drew** and **comp_drew.**
But comparing these two variables to decide a winner isnt working for me..

Answer (score 0):

you_drew and comp_drew are strings. Comparing strings via ">" or any other comparison operator will simply compare the strings by their **size**.

In your string array, you have the strings in the form of "ace \3", which I don't understand. If the 3 is the value of the array, you can do this:

```
if(you_drew.back() > comp_drew.back())
{
    cout << "You Won!" << endl;
}
```

.back() will return the last character in the string. You can convert them to  integers, but there's no need since the values are all one digit long.

On the other hand, if the value of the card is simply determined by how far in the array it is, then you can do this:

```
pair<string, int> draw_card()
{
    int random_index = rand() % 52;
    string card = cards[random_index];
    return { card, random_index };
}


pair<string, int> you_drew = draw_card();
cout << "You drew: " << you_drew.first << endl;
...
if (you_drew.second > comp_drew.second)
        cout << "You Won!" << endl;
```

In this case, you return the index of the card, you return both the string and the index, and then the card with the highest index in the array wins.

Comment: The \3 \4 \5 \6 is the symbols of the cards. Hearts, Diamond, clubs and Spades. Thank you very much for trying to help! I will try the last tip! :)

Comment: Hey zapshe If i implement your solution, how do i make sure there isnt a duplicate? The game is draw 2 cards tom the deck (the array) but with this solution there is sometimes duplicate, the same card can be drawn... Do you know how I do to make sure the same card cant be drawn from the array?

Comment: @gunnar20008 You can add a parameter to the function, an integer. Set it to -1 by default, by the second time you call the function will look like draw_card(you_drew.second);

Then you can simply loop, while random_index == int, make another random number.